# Calculate total using dynamic gridview?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 if(ddlindentno.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
    {                      
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GVFeedsaleOrder.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddltype");
            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlqty");
            TextBox txtnufbags = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtnoofbags");
            TextBox txtrateperkg = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtrateperkg");

            if (txtnufbags.Text.Trim() != "" && txtrateperkg.Text.Trim() != "" && 
    ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && ddl1.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
            {
                //CalculateTotal();
                objfeedretailPL.sno = Convert.ToInt32(ddlindentno.SelectedValue);
                objfeedretailPL.type = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue);
                objfeedretailPL.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
                objfeedretailPL.noofbags = Convert.ToInt32(txtnufbags.Text.ToString());
                objfeedretailPL.rateperkg = Convert.ToSingle(txtrateperkg.Text.ToString());                      
                objfeedretailPL.username = Session["username"].ToString();

                int baginkgs = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
                int noofbags = Convert.ToInt32(txtnufbags.Text);
                float ratepkg = Convert.ToSingle(txtrateperkg.Text);
                float recamt = Convert.ToSingle(lblamtrec.Text.ToString());

                float totprvtotal = 0.0f;
                totprvtotal = noofbags * ratepkg * ratepkg;
            }
      }
  }
```

Here i calculate the first row of dynamic grid..now it's total add the next row..how can i add 
that..please help me

Comment: You can have a variable that is defined before the foreach statement to store the last calculation result and then add it to the next calculation.

Comment: Store a calculated value in a variable & add it to the next calculated row..

Answer (score 1):

```
float totprvtotal = 0.0f; // Declare a varaible

if(ddlindentno.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
    {                      
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GVFeedsaleOrder.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddltype");
            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlqty");
            TextBox txtnufbags = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtnoofbags");
            TextBox txtrateperkg = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtrateperkg");

            if (txtnufbags.Text.Trim() != "" && txtrateperkg.Text.Trim() != "" && 
    ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && ddl1.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
            {
                //CalculateTotal();
                objfeedretailPL.sno = Convert.ToInt32(ddlindentno.SelectedValue);
                objfeedretailPL.type = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue);
                objfeedretailPL.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
                objfeedretailPL.noofbags = Convert.ToInt32(txtnufbags.Text.ToString());
                objfeedretailPL.rateperkg = Convert.ToSingle(txtrateperkg.Text.ToString());                      
                objfeedretailPL.username = Session["username"].ToString();

                int baginkgs = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
                int noofbags = Convert.ToInt32(txtnufbags.Text);
                float ratepkg = Convert.ToSingle(txtrateperkg.Text);
                float recamt = Convert.ToSingle(lblamtrec.Text.ToString());


                totprvtotal = noofbags * ratepkg * ratepkg;
            }
      }
  }
```

credit goes to  @Ashish Charan

Answer (score 1):

Pls try below...

```
if(ddlindentno.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
{                      

     float totprvtotal = 0.0f;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GVFeedsaleOrder.Rows)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddltype");
        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlqty");
        TextBox txtnufbags = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtnoofbags");
        TextBox txtrateperkg = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtrateperkg");

        if (txtnufbags.Text.Trim() != "" && txtrateperkg.Text.Trim() != "" && 
ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && ddl1.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
        {
            //CalculateTotal();
            objfeedretailPL.sno = Convert.ToInt32(ddlindentno.SelectedValue);
            objfeedretailPL.type = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue);
            objfeedretailPL.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
            objfeedretailPL.noofbags = Convert.ToInt32(txtnufbags.Text.ToString());
            objfeedretailPL.rateperkg = Convert.ToSingle(txtrateperkg.Text.ToString());                      
            objfeedretailPL.username = Session["username"].ToString();

            int baginkgs = Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
            int noofbags = Convert.ToInt32(txtnufbags.Text);
            float ratepkg = Convert.ToSingle(txtrateperkg.Text);
            float recamt = Convert.ToSingle(lblamtrec.Text.ToString());


            totprvtotal = noofbags * ratepkg * ratepkg + totprvtotal;
        }
  }
```

}